# Onelogin CLI Authentication Failure

Tags: onelogin

I already have an AWS App that is currently working and I have Java 8 installed. When I tried the  onelogin-python-aws-assume-role tool, it worked fine and I was able to login using https://github.com/onelogin/onelogin-python-aws-assume-role

but for some reason the java one doesn't work https://github.com/onelogin/onelogin-aws-cli-assume-role.

I followed all the steps here https://developers.onelogin.com/api-docs/1/samples/aws-cli

1 - I created Developer API Keys,
2 - I updated onelogin.sdk.properties with the API Keys
3 - Downloaded the latest onelogin-aws-cli.jar
4 - Ran "java -jar onelogin-aws-cli.jar --profile master --appid 33333 --subdomain companyname --region eu-west-2 --username myusername"

I then get the following output:

OneLogin AWS Assume Role Tool

15:12:33.727 [main] DEBUG com.onelogin.sdk.util.Settings - properties file onelogin.sdk.properties loaded succesfully
Exception in thread "main" OAuthProblemException{error='Unauthorized', description='Authentication Failure', uri='null', state='401', scope='null', redirectUri='null', responseStatus=401, parameters={}}
        at org.apache.oltu.oauth2.common.exception.OAuthProblemException.error(OAuthProblemException.java:59)
        at org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client.validator.OAuthClientValidator.validateErrorResponse(OAuthClientValidator.java:63)
        at org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client.validator.OAuthClientValidator.validate(OAuthClientValidator.java:48)
        at org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client.response.OAuthClientResponse.validate(OAuthClientResponse.java:127)
        at com.onelogin.sdk.conn.OneloginOAuthJSONAccessTokenResponse.init(OneloginOAuthJSONAccessTokenResponse.java:24)
        at org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client.response.OAuthClientResponse.init(OAuthClientResponse.java:101)
        at org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client.response.OAuthAccessTokenResponse.init(OAuthAccessTokenResponse.java:60)
        at org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client.response.OAuthClientResponse.init(OAuthClientResponse.java:120)
        at org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client.response.OAuthClientResponseFactory.createCustomResponse(OAuthClientResponseFactory.java:82)
        at com.onelogin.sdk.conn.OneloginURLConnectionClient.execute(OneloginURLConnectionClient.java:75)
        at com.onelogin.sdk.conn.Client.getAccessToken(Client.java:168)
        at com.onelogin.aws.assume.role.cli.OneloginAWSCLI.main(OneloginAWSCLI.java:160)

Answer (score 1):

I resolved it in the end.. Turns out I used the wrong onelogin.sdk.properties